# using Azure file service in Angular client

Tags: angularjs, azure, azure-storage, file-storage

In our project we are tying to upload file from angular client to azure file service using SAS URL.

We are following this URL as reference while making PUT call: "https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn194276.aspx"

However we get an error related to content-length or Range header, it says that value is not correctly set.

Any pointers to what are we doing wrong here? As mentioned earlier, we are trying to write to file directly from angular client and there is no WEB API or middle layer service in between.

Update ----------------------------------------------------------------

Code :
JS:

```
$scope.addTesting = function() {
    var f = document.getElementById('file').files[0];
    // r = new FileReader();
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("file", f);
    // r.onloadend = function(e) {
    // var data = e.target.result;
    // console.log(data);
    $http({
        method: "PUT",
        url: {put range URL + SAS URL},
        headers: {
            'x-ms-write': 'update',
            'x-ms-range': 'bytes=0-239',
            // 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            'content-length': 240,

        },
        data: fd
    }).success(function(res) {
        console.log(res);
    }).error(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
    // };
    // r.readAsBinaryString(f);
    // r.readAsArrayBuffer(f);
};
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <input type="file" id="file" name="file"/>
  <button ng-click="addTesting()">Add</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: forgot response details:  http://take.ms/eXUAC

Comment: Please share the source code. My guess is that the size of the content sent in request is different than the value specified in the content-length request header.

Comment: Added code in original post, content length is 240 and we are setting range as 0-239, i think that's correct

Comment: How is this related at all with C#? This is all js

Comment: This is resolved.